MSP430F5529LP : Unable to change clock source to XT2
I am working on MSP430F5529LP development board. By default it runs at 1MHz. The development board also comes with a 4MHz crystal which can be used as a clock source at XT2. I am trying to do that, but for some reason, the code gets stuck in a while loop because the XT1LFOFFG flag is never cleared. Here is my code for reference:
void initClocks(void) 
{
    // Step 1: Configure XT2 pins
    P5SEL |= BIT2 | BIT3;      // Select XT2 function on P5.2 and P5.3
    // Step 1: Disable XT1
       UCSCTL6 |= XT1OFF;         // Explicitly turn off XT1

       // Step 2: Set ACLK to use REFO
       UCSCTL4 = (UCSCTL4 & ~SELA_7) | SELA__REFOCLK; // Use REFO for ACLK

       // Step 3: Configure XT2 for MCLK and SMCLK
       P5SEL |= BIT2 | BIT3;      // Enable XT2 function on P5.2 and P5.3
       UCSCTL6 &= ~XT2OFF;        // Enable XT2 oscillator

       // Step 4: Wait for XT2 to stabilize
       do {
           UCSCTL7 &= ~(XT1LFOFFG | XT2OFFG); // Clear XT1 and XT2 fault flags
           SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;                 // Clear global oscillator fault flag
           __delay_cycles(5000);              // Delay for stabilization
       } while (SFRIFG1 & OFIFG);             // Wait until faults are cleared

       // Step 5: Set MCLK and SMCLK to use XT2
       UCSCTL4 = (UCSCTL4 & ~(SELM_7 | SELS_7)) | SELM__XT2CLK | SELS__XT2CLK;

       // Step 6: Set dividers (optional)
       UCSCTL5 &= ~(DIVM_7 | DIVS_7); // Clear dividers
       UCSCTL5 |= DIVM__1 | DIVS__1;  // No division for MCLK and SMCLK
}

It gets stuck in Step-4.
What could be the problem?

I would add some troubleshooting code. Save the register values in global variables. Pause the code and examine them.

Where did you get this code from? Did you make any changes?

@CL. I got the code from internet (random googling) and I did add the code to stop the XT1 because when I checked the fault registers, I found that the error flag of XT1 was set.

You should start with code that is known to work. Go to https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F5529 → Design & development → Software development → SLAC300 C Examples, and look at MSP430F55xx_UCS_08.c.

The clock system automatically tries to use XT1 when any module requests it. To prevent the XT1 errors, you must reconfigure both ACLK and FLL to use another clock source.
In the loop, you should clear all possible fault flags, including the DCO fault flag.
The call to __delay_cycles() does not stabilize anything and is not necessary.
P5.2/P5.3 are configured twice, in steps 1 and 3. Only one is necessary.
After the crystal has started up, you can reduce the XT2 drive strength.


I found the example and implemented it. Thanks. My actual goal is as follows: Use XT2 as the main clock source for MCLK, SMCLK and ACLK. The crystal on XT2 is of 4MHz and I want to run the MCLK and SMCLK at 24MHz. I have found some code and it did increase the MCLK to 24MHz, but I do not understand it and I would appreciate the help to understand it better.
https://pastebin.com/4wSDE9si
How is it multiplying the clock to run the MCLK at 24MHz?

To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

I figured out most of the details. Thanks a lot, again.
